# MVC3 - Scaffold Template (Field Order)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding, scaffold

When using the following dialog to add a view, is there anyway you can state in what order you want the fields created?

[image]

I tried [Column(Order=0)] ::: [Column(Order=12)], but no joy!

Thanks Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because the Details.tt template (as well as all the others) does not do any ordering when generating the markup. More details on how to customize the templates: [ASP.NET MVC custom T4 templates for views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009067/asp-net-mvc-custom-t4-templates-for-views)